# Azure timer function complains about not returning Task

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a small Azure timer based function and it has been running for quite some time, today I upgraded some packages and SDK to their newest versions and also Tried this in VS2019 but I am running into some issues.

The function is declared as follows

```
public static async void RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
```

and the error message in the cli func.exe is as follows

```
[24/6/2019 05:01:11] Function 'Items' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
```

I am running the following versions of nuget pkgs

```
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb.Core - 2.4.1
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions - 1.0.29
Microsoft.NETCore.App - 2.2.5
```

The function does not run due to a memory error in the following part of the code, not sure if this is related though

I am getting an out of memory crash at the following step

```
decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Seems like the function works with large files - that can cause the out of memory problem.

Comment: Ok is there a way around this? it works fine using VS2017 with a copy paste of the code so I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: without having some source code and examples of what you've retired so far, it would be impossible for anyone to help with the memory consumption. And,  once again, that's a separate issue which should be asked as a separate question. This one is about returning a Task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function has to return a Task, otherwise the framework cannot track the completion of your function. That means you have no guarantees of execution, the framework can abruptly terminate it. Just change async void to async Task:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task RunAsync(...)
```

The memory issue is not related.

Comment: Ok so how do I adjust the function to return the task? That’s the template from VS2019 I just assumed it was correct

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't expect that in a template. Updated the reply.

Comment: I would add if you're not using any `await` call in your code, you can simply use `public static void Run(...)`.

Comment: Makes sense Thomas, I wouldn't expect `async void` though.